# Python module globals versus __init__ globals

Tags: python, global

Apologies, somewhat confused Python newbie question. Let's say I have a module called `animals.py`.......

```
globvar = 1

class dog: 
   def bark(self):
      print globvar

class cat:
   def miaow(self):
      print globvar
```

What is the difference between this and

```
class dog:
   def __init__(self):
      global globvar

   def bark(self):
      print globvar

class cat:
   def miaow(self):
      print globvar
```

Assuming I always instantiate a dog first?

I guess my question is, is there any difference? In the second example, does initiating the `dog` create a module level `globvar` just like in the first example, that will behave the same and have the same scope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`global` doesn't create a new variable, it just states that this name should refer to a global variable instead of a local one. Usually assignments to variables in a function/class/... refer to local variables. For example take a function like this:

```
def increment(n)
  # this creates a new local m
  m = n+1
  return m
```

Here a new local variable `m` is created, even if there might be a global variable `m` already existing. This is what you usually want since some function call shouldn't unexpectedly modify variables in the surrounding scopes. If you indeed want to modify a global variable and not create a new local one, you can use the `global` keyword:

```
def increment(n)
  global increment_calls
  increment_calls += 1
  return n+1
```

In your case `global` in the constructor doesn't create any variables, further attempts to access `globvar` fail:

```
>>> import animals
>>> d = animals.dog()
>>> d.bark()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "animals.py", line 7, in bark
    print globvar
NameError: global name 'globvar' is not defined
```

But if you would actually assign a value to `globvar` in the constructor, a module-global variable would be created when you create a dog:

```
class dog:
   def __init__(self):
      global globvar
      globvar = 1
...
```

Execution:

```
>>> import animals
>>> d = animals.dog()
>>> d.bark()
1
>>> print animals.globvar
1
```

Comment: Class stuff, sth. Thank you. Perfectly answers the question

Answer (score 4):

No, the `global` statement only matters when you're *assigning* to a global variable within a method or function. So that `__init__` is irrelevant -- it does **not** create the global, because it's not assigning anything to it.

Comment: Except that cat class will return an error, right Alex, if a dog hasn't been instantiated first? If I don't have the global globvar statement in the dog's __init__ then cat returns an error. But otherwise the scope of the two is identical. Thanks for help.

Comment: In your second example, you will always get an error because you never created globvar. The "global" keyword does not create a global variable. What the global statement does is tell Python that you are referring to a global variable, and not creating a new, separate local variable that has the same name. As Alex said, this only matters when you are assigning a value to a global variable from within a method or function.

Comment: @Thomas, @htw is exactly correct: to make it work as you think it should, that __init__ requires an assignment to globvar (and _then_ it will fail if you instantiate a cat before a dog).

Comment: Thanks htw and Alex. I guess my old Pascal/c experience (rusty!) thinking got me to believe "global globvar" declared a variable. classic error of a newbie Pythonista still living in the old paradigm. I consider myself enlightend.